# how to make the dynamic drop down list stay in one value after selected java script

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, dropdown

Right now I have a dynamic list that read in from a json file to get all the countries name, but I am not sure how to make it stay at a certain country name after clicking it. Assume I pick a country name Canada, I want it to stay at Canada. Right now I will jump back to the name on the top of the list. Can someone show me how to make it stay at certain country name?
below is my html code and javascript code

```
    <select id="chooseName"  name="" onchange="changeVector()">   
    <option value=" empty"  selected = "selected"></option>
    </select>

    <script>
    $( "select" )
    .change(function () {
    var str = "";
         $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
        //str += $( this ).text() + "qwe ";
    });
        //$( "div" ).text( str );
    })
    .change();



    function changeVector(){
        Ajax3();
        addOption2();
        nameQuery();

    }

    //reading the data
    var Ajax3 = function ()  
    {      //var obj=document.getElementById('vector')
        //var name= "countries.shp"


    $.getJSON ("placelist/cb_2016_us_state_20m.shp.txt", function                        
    (data)  
    { 

       $.each (data, function (i, item)  
        {    for ( placeKey in item){

              placelist[i]=item[placeKey]


          }
          placelist.sort();


       });

    });  

    }  
    function  addOption2(){setTimeout(function(){ 
    //find the object according to the id，
        document.getElementById("chooseName").innerHTML = "";
        var  obj=document.getElementById( 'chooseName' );
        //find an option

        for(i=0;i<placelist.length;i++){
        obj.add( new  Option( placelist[i] , placelist[i] ));
        }

        },10); 
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: not really clear what you're asking, if you mean `keep track of the selected option so that it remains selected`, you might check `localStorage`

Answer (score 0):

If it's a select input, add the "readonly" attribute, if it's a custom element, remove the listeners or in css => pointer-event: none;